# Why are ListView and grouped CollectionViewSource not showing any items?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Here is code (minified):

```
<Page
    x:Class="Compote.HubPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Compote"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    DataContext="{Binding HubViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Background="{ThemeResource  ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultItemTemplate">
            <Border Margin="0,0,0,9.5" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="170"/>
                    <StackPanel Margin="15,12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="14.5" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{ThemeResource CustomListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource PriceConverter}}" Style="{ThemeResource CustomListViewItemSecondaryTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Weight, Converter={StaticResource WeightConverter}}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionViewSourceCategories" Source="{Binding Categories}" IsSourceGrouped="True" ItemsPath="Items" />        
    </Page.Resources>


<ListView AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListViewSection4"
          AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
          SelectionMode="None"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSourceCategories}}"
          ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultItemTemplate}" AllowDrop="True">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

As you can see, the `CollectionViewSource` is binded to the `ListView` and its `IsSourceGrouped` property is set to `True`. `Categories` contains 2 categories with 3 items in each category. But the `ListView` doesn't show anything, it's totally empty. What's wrong?

Comment: What happens if you set the source just with Categories in the Listview, just to watch if appears the data?

Comment: @Juan Pablo Garcia Coello If I just bind `Categories` to the `ListView` the list of categories appears as expected.

Comment: And categories in HubViewModel has implemented Inotifypropertychanged?

Comment: @Juan Pablo Garcia Coello Of course. I use MVVM Light.

Comment: can you show the Categories code?

Comment: @Juan Pablo Garcia Coello `Categories` is the list of objects of type `Category` with child list `Items`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an itemPresenter in the GroupStyle.

```
            <ListView Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSourceCategories}}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <!-- ItemsPresenter -->
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="NAME" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Something else that might be helpful if you're grouping items Is to add a PropertyGroupDescription to your collectionViewSource:
First add this to your declarations:
xmlns:dat="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework" xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"

then your CollectionViewSource:

```
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionViewSourceCategories" Source="{Binding Categories}">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Categories" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Names" />
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
```

This will group by your category, then sort by names. here's the link explaining it:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx
```

hope this helps!

Comment: The `ListView` is still not showing any groups and items.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind to the `View` property of the `CollectionViewSource`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSourceCategories}, Path=View}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing has changed.